# Do Until ... Loop doesn't exit loop even when condition = true

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio

I'm programming a program that needs to read a file and I have a `Do ... Until` loop that I use to use the info in that file. I want to end the loop when the file ends, so the loop looks like this:

```
 Do Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" Or Reader.ReadLine = "</kml>" Or Reader.EndOfStream = True
```

Originally, it was just `Reader.ReadLine = "</kml>"` but since that wasn't exiting the loop when the file ended (even though the file does end with `</kml>`) I wrote the other ones, but none of them make it stop! I always get a `NullPointerException` when the file ends because I'm trying to read a file that doesn't have anything else to read. I even put an If statement inside the loop that checks if the file ended and if it does, it does `Exit Do`, but that doesn't work either.

This is my code (all of the checks to see if the file ended are there to see if they solve the problem but they don't and I plan on removing them when I solve this):

```
Do Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" Or Reader.ReadLine = "</kml>" Or Reader.EndOfStream = True
    If Reader.EndOfStream = True Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        lineactual = Reader.ReadLine
    End If

    If lineactual.Contains("<Folder>") = True Then
        lblcategoria.Text = RemoveHTML(Reader.ReadLine)
        lineactual = Reader.ReadLine
    Else
        Do Until Reader.ReadLine.Contains("<Folder>")
            Reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End If

    Do Until lineactual.Contains("<Placemark>") Or Reader.EndOfStream
        Reader.ReadLine()
    Loop

    If Reader.ReadLine.Contains("<name>") = True And Reader.EndOfStream = False Then
        lblpregunta.Text = lineactual
    ElseIf Reader.EndOfStream = True Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: You realize each call to `ReadLine` reads another line, don't you? So `Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" Or Reader.ReadLine = "</kml>"` reads two lines?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" Or Reader.ReadLine = "</kml>" read 2. How would I read a line and store it so I can use it multiple times?

Comment: You store it in a variable?..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what type of object is the Reader that you have in your code. Is it a [TextStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724(v=vs.60).aspx) which was returned by a [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx).[OpenTextFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx) function?

I suppose it might be the case that every line ends with a newline character, so you should either try it with:

```
Do Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" & vbNewLine
```

or

```
Do Until Reader.ReadLine = "</Document>" & chr(13)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I used the code in another thread to read the file, I'm kind of a noob with VBA. It's  Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(abrir_mapa.FileName)

Comment: I think that this is actually not a VBA Question. Your snippet sounds rather like a VB.Net code.

Comment: Are they different? My bad, I am using vb.net